# liferay 6.1.2 CE GA3

Tags: liferay

I am installing Liferay version 6.1.2 CE GA3/Tomcat bundle on a Linux based VPS, but cant get past the basic config screen.  I  have installed version 6.0.1 and had it working fine, but cannot get this newer version to work.

When I click on the finish button in the basic config screen, to install the portal, the connection to the server drops out and I can go no further.  I get the basic 'Problem loading page' screen in Firefox:

```
  Unable to connect

  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 198.38.90.216:8080.

  The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
  moments.

 If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
 connection.

If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Does anybody have any advice on how to get this version installed correctly?

Thanks in advance.
Jen

Comment: Ok, I found a suggestion on another forum and deleted the data file before running the startup.  This got me one step further before i lost the connection to the server.  I got a screen saying that the configuration was saved successfully, but when I hit the button to access the portal, I get dropped out again and cannot connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try follwing these steps.
 1. remove all liferay files.
 2. install every thing again.
 3. Start liferay using startup.sh with hsql.
 4. apply basic configuration, accept terms and conditions, answer the security ques and give a password.
 4. now change the properties to mysql in portal-ext.properties.
 5. Start liferay again.
 6. Try logging in.